# Pandas dataframe reduce / add rows based on key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reduce

I'm struggling a bit with kind of simple problem. Hope there is also a simple solution for it. My Dataframe looks like this.

```
DataFrame:
8 buy  4
7 sell 1
6 buy  1
5 sell 3
4 sell 10  
3 buy  100
2 buy  110
1 buy  120
```

Is there a way to add same orders that come after each other? So transform the df to:

```
DataFrame:
8 buy  4
7 sell 1
6 buy  1
4 sell 3 + 10 
1 buy  100 + 110 + 120
```

My problem is a bit more complicated. I think it can be solved with iterrows but was hoping that there is a more simple solution.

Comment: What is the exact criterion on merging and keep individual entries? How do you decide to keep e.g. the first two buy rows but merge the last three?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `agg` with `groupby`

```
df.groupby((df.b!=df.b.shift()).ne(0).cumsum()).agg({'a':'last','c':lambda x : '+'.join(x.astype(str)),'b':'first'})
Out[1227]: 
   a            c     b
b                      
1  8            4   buy
2  7            1  sell
3  6            1   buy
4  4         3+10  sell
5  1  100+110+120   buy
```

Data input :

```
df
Out[1228]: 
   a     b    c
0  8   buy    4
1  7  sell    1
2  6   buy    1
3  5  sell    3
4  4  sell   10
5  3   buy  100
6  2   buy  110
7  1   buy  120
```

More info :

```
(df.b!=df.b.shift()).ne(0).cumsum()
Out[1229]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    4
5    5
6    5
7    5
Name: b, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Amazing that it works that way! Thanks a lot! It's a nice trick with cumsum!

Comment: @MichaelRazum yw~ : -) happy coding

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might be looking for the actual sums rather than a string representation of the addition.  Say you have the following:

```
   id_ order   px
0    8   buy    4
1    7  sell    1
2    6   buy    1
3    5  sell    3
4    4  sell   10
5    3   buy  100
6    2   buy  110
7    1   buy  120
```

If that's the case, here you could use:

```
df['order_bin'] = np.where(df.order=='buy', 1, 0)
df['group'] = (df.order_bin.diff().fillna(0.) != 0.).cumsum()
df.groupby('group')['px'].sum()

0      4
1      1
2      1
3     13
4    330
```